Python pyvenv.cfg Dynamic directory
Is there anyway in the pyvenv.cfg file to dynamically change the users directory dependant on who is logged onto the system? I've created a script on my local computer with the following directory
C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe

Ideally I would like it to dynamically change itself to the profile that's logged in and running the script.
C:\Users\SERVER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe

To give an overview of what I'm trying to achieve. I have created a script which I want to run on Task Scheduler everyday. I currently have it working on my local computer, but would prefer it to run on a server which I know will be turned on when the script needs running. I have seen a suggestion that I can run add to my powershell script to change the pyvenv.cfg file everytime the script is run, but would prefer to keep this within python if possible.
Thanks in advance
